# content.min.js / overlay.min.js errors on load in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, console.log

When opening a page of our website I sometimes see these errors, but i cannot identify what causes them. (I'm only aware about the scrollArrow.js one). Because of those functionalities like saving text do not work.

Is there a way to see what exactly is null and failing? I can see multiple issues with 'content.min.js' and 'overlay.min.js' but i'm not sure how to debug those.

This only happens sometimes - one idea I had was that I could be related to the load time a page needs, but I cannot always reproduce the issue.

Any advices are greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: can we see the html where the js is loaded ?

Comment: It contains private data so I'm afraid I can't share, but it is basically a page with multiple input fields that save whatever is entered in the input on .focusout